# Entity framework, POCO, howto report progress to user during DB initialize?

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to figure out a way so I can report the progress on initialize DB schema stage
to user though a progress bar.

The problem is: I don't know where to call the 'ReportProgress' function? I am currently overwrite 'Seed' function to populate initial DB data, could I overwrite Database 'Initialize' function so the progress could be updated after the creation of each table?

**EDIT:**
According to this article: [Creating a Code First Database Initializer Strategy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203618/Creating-a-Code-First-Database-Initializer-Strateg)

Implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer` and its function `InitializeDatabase` and
put my own database and table creating code inside should do what I want. Then instead
of inside `Seed` function, I could raise events inside `InitializeDatabase`. That should working, but I have yet reach a point that I need go though all these trouble to show progress of DB initialize to end user, now a waiting cursor works for me.

Comment: Do you manually create tables inside the `Seed` method?

Comment: No, the 'Seed' only used to generate data. Ok if I do that I can update progress inside 'Seed' method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF initializers do not expose the progress through any events.

Declare some events that you want to raise when some state changes in the seed method.

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
    public event EventHandler<SeedStateChangeEventArgs> SeedStateChange;

    protected virtual void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
       // create a table
       OnSeedStateChange(new SeedStateChangeEventArgs { Table = "Foo" });

       // create another table
       OnSeedStateChange(new SeedStateChangeEventArgs { Table = "Bar" });
    }

    protected virtual void OnSeedStateChange(SeedStateChangeEventArgs args)
    {
         // raise event here
    }
}
```

Then in your `Form`

```
var initializer = new MyInitializer();
initializer.SeedStateChange += MyStateChangeHandler;
Database.SetInitializer(initializer);

var context = new MyContext();
context.Database.Initialize(false);
```

This is just an outline of the concept. I haven't tried this

Comment: Hi, according to this document for 'Seed' method': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221%28v=vs.103%29.aspx - "When overridden adds data to the context for seeding. The default implementation does nothing.", doesn't looks like using 'Seed' in that way will work, as DB structure should already been created before calling 'Seed'.

Comment: @pstar call `base.Seed()` inside your overridden method

Comment: I put base.Seed(context) on first line of my override `Seed` Method, but the DB structure already been created at this point when I do a debug/break. I think I need overwrite `InitializeDatabase` or `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: happy with the idea you provided, but I do think I need use `InitializeDatabase` instead of `Seed` method